# Unable to execute 'cd' in adb shell

Tags: java, android, shell

I am trying to execute `cd /sys/class/power_supply/battery && cat uevent` command in `ADB SHELL` and weave an `ArrayList` out of the info. But, it fails to work and an empty is returned. Though when I execute `ls` replacing `cd /sys/class/power_supply/battery && cat uevent`, the `ArrayList` gets populated. Though the path is easily accessible using the `terminal` app!
What is wrong ?

```
ArrayList<String> info = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("adb shell");
        process.waitFor();
        process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cd /sys/class/power_supply/battery && cat uevent");
        BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line=buf.readLine())!=null) {
            info.add(line);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }

    Log.i("INFORMATION",info.toString());
}
```

Comment: Why do you need cd? You could simply do `cat /sys/class/power_supply/battery/uevent`